# A hierarchical model with conjugate hyperprior

Tags: bayesian, inference, hierarchical-bayesian, hyperparameter, conjugate-prior

I have a modeling problem that I am trying to formulate in a Bayesian manner to do inference.
Basically, I have a prior where the variance is unknown, and we want to treat it as uncertain (though with a prior), in addition to an unknown variance for the likelihood term. I have now understood that this is then a hierarchical model (I'm new), where the prior variance is the *second level of hierarchy* (correct me if I'm wrong).
The model parameters are denoted as $\theta$, the likelihood variance is denoted as $\sigma_1^2$, while the prior variance is denoted as $\sigma_2^2$.
Therefore, applying the relevant independences, I believe that the following is an accurate description of the problem:

$$p(\theta, \sigma_1^2, \sigma_2^2 | y) \propto p(y| \theta, \sigma_1^2) p(\theta | \sigma_2^2) p(\sigma_2^2) p(\sigma_1^2)$$
where the last three terms make up the prior $p(\theta, \sigma_1^2, \sigma_2^2)$.

I would like to define a simple version of this problem where we can work in closed form, i.e. have a prior conjugate to the likelihood, though this seems difficult (I have made some attempts with multinormal-inverse-wishart - i.e. assuming an inverse gamma prior distribution for the variances and a normal for $\theta|\sigma_2^2$) - even though wikipedia mentions *conjugate hyperpriors*, the references therein have not helped too much with this part.

**Example of this simple form: linear regression w/ prior:** Likelihood stems from: $y|\mu, \sigma^2 \sim N_n(X\mu, \sigma_1^2I_n)$, priors: $\mu | \sigma_2^2 \sim N(\mu_B, \sigma_2^2 P)$ where $P, X$ and $\mu_B$ are known, and $\sigma_1^2 \sim IG(a_1, b_1)$, $\sigma_2^2 \sim IG(a_2, b_2)$ with some specified hyperparameters $a_1, b_1, a_2, b_2$.

I am starting to suspect that I actually **can not** estimate both $\sigma_1^2$ and $\sigma_2^2$, but I can hopefully estimate their ratio, i.e. estimate an $\alpha = \sigma_1^2 / \sigma_2^2$. I suspect that the example above has to be edited (simplified).
So my question is,

- Is the prior in my example conjugate? Does there exist a slightly different conjugate hyperprior for this scenario (estimating both the variances)? Perhaps elsewhere in the exponential family? Or is there a contradiction hidden here?
- If not, can we make it work with estimating the ratio $\alpha$? How? I realize that if we know $\alpha$ then it definitely works with NIW. Possible to use empirical Bayes to estimate $\alpha$?

Greatful for any pointers in clarifying this.

Comment: It will help if you clarify certain aspects of your question. Specifically what kind of question you are trying to address ? I guess that if you mention inverse-Wishart as conjugate prior you are in a linear regression context. Also please formalize a little bit more your question, before community can provide any guidance.

Comment: Alright, thanks, I will try to add an example. However, I want to keep the topic a bit open, since there might be a general answer given the hierarchical structure.

Comment: The book "Kendall's Advanced Theory of Statistics: Volume 2B (Bayesian inference)" discusses this type of setting in one chapter and is worth reading. You can do closed form solutions, if $\sigma_2^2$ is known, but not if it's unknown. If the variation via $\sigma_2$ is over every unit (i.e. there's no grouping of multiple observations with the same $\theta$), $\sigma_2$ is redundant and cannot be identified (except via strong enough priors). If that's not the case, it can be identified, but there's no closed form approach.

Comment: That sounds very helpful! Thanks. But we can use a sampling based approach to compute the posterior, right? Or is this identifiability more severe? And some empirical bayes approach is also possible, right? Uplifting to see that it is at least considered an advanced topic;)

Comment: I am not able to get hold of the book untill a few weeks at least ... no online version and not available in my uni library.

Comment: @Björn do you have an idea of where in the book this is considered?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/86652/bj%c3%b6rn if you don't mind :)

Comment: I think it was either in the second half of chapter 11 ("The linear model") or in chapter 14 ("Other standard models") regarding multivariate normal/multivariate linear model/spatial temporal structures.

Comment: great, thanks. I guess some of the point is stated in 11.48 and 11.62.